# Generalization of $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cosh x d x$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, hyperbolic-functions, gaussian-integral

Recently I had just met a solution on the integral using the power series of $\cosh x$. I wish to generalize it by the result the [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x+b)^2} d x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

First of all, I, by definition, express the integrand in terms of $e^x$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-a x^2} \cosh (b x) d x 
= & \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(e^{-a x^2+b x}+e^{-a x^2-b x}\right) d x \\
= & \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(e^{-a\left(x-\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2+\frac{b^2}{4 a}}+e^{-a\left(x+\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2+\frac{b^2}{4 a}}\right) d x \\
= & \left.\frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a\left(x-\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2} d x+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a\left(x+\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2} d x\right] \\
= & \frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}}{4}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\right)\\=&\frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $a>0$ and $b$ is real.

---

**Am I correct? Is there any other method?**

Your comments and alternative methods are highly appreciated.

Comment: yes it's correct... why do you think it may be not correct ?

Comment: Because I am not familiar with integral involving hyperbolic functions. I post it as I want to learn more methods.

Comment: It looks like there is a sign error in the second and third line. The second exponent should read $-a(x+b/2a)$, shouldn't it? It has no bearing on the final result though.

Comment: Thank you very much, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another (still harder) solution. For fixed $a>0$ let
$$F(b)=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\cosh (bx)\,dx$$
Then
$${d \over db}F(b)=\int\limits_{0}^\infty xe^{-ax^2}\sinh (bx)\,dx\\
\overset{\rm by\ parts}{=} -{1\over 2a}e^{-ax^2}\sinh(bx)\bigg\vert_0^\infty  +{b\over 2a}\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\cosh(bx)\,dx\\ ={b\over 2a}F(b)$$
Thus
$\displaystyle F(b)=F(0)\exp\left ({b^2\over 4a}\right).$ Next $$F(0)=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,dx={1\over \sqrt{a}} \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx={\sqrt{\pi}\over 2\sqrt{a}}$$

Comment: I just thought of Feynman whose trick gave such a nice solution! Thank you for your alternative method.

Answer (score 4):

We are given
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x+b)^2} d x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}},\quad
a>0,b\in\mathbb R .
\tag0$$
First, generalize this to
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x+b)^2} d x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}},
\quad a>0,b\in\mathbb C .
\tag1$$
To prove it, note that the LHS is an analytic function of $b$ [by Morera], and constant on the real line, therefore constant on $\mathbb C$.

Next, if $\beta$ is real, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)\cos\left(\beta x\right)dx
&= \operatorname{Re}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)\exp(i\beta x)\;dx
\\ &= \operatorname{Re}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-a\left(x-\frac{i\beta}{2a}\right)^2\right)\exp\left(\frac{-\beta^2}{4a}\right)\;dx
\\ &= \exp\left(\frac{-\beta^2}{4a}\right)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} .
\end{align}
Again, both sides are analytic in $\beta$, and we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)\cos\left(\beta x\right)dx
=\exp\left(\frac{-\beta^2}{4a}\right)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}},
\quad a>0, \beta\in \mathbb C .
\tag3$$
Therefore, for $a>0, b \in \mathbb C$,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)\cosh\left(b x\right)dx
& =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)\cos\left(i b x\right)dx
\\ &= \exp\left(\frac{-(ib)^2}{4a}\right)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
= \exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your alternative method which shows wonderfully the use of Gaussian integral in general and $\cosh(y)=\cos(iy)$

Comment: Note the formula holds for complex $b$, not merely for real $b$.

Comment: You are right! Agree.

Answer (score 3):

A possibly harder solution:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)\cosh\left(bx\right)dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(bx\right)^{2k}}{\left(2k\right)!}dx \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{b^{2k}}{\left(2k\right)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2k}\exp\left(-ax^{2}\right)dx \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{b^{2k}}{\left(2k\right)!}\frac{\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{2a^{k+\frac{1}{2}}} \tag{1}\\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{b^{2}}{a}\right)^{k}\frac{1}{\left(2k\right)!}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{b^{2}}{a}\right)^{k}\frac{1}{\left(2k\right)!}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left(2k\right)!}{4^{k}k!} \tag{2} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{b^{2}}{4a}\right)^{k}\cdot\frac{1}{k!} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}\exp\left(\frac{b^{2}}{4a}\right)
\end{align}
$$

where $(1)$ is derived from [this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html#:%7E:text=The%20Gaussian%20integral%2C%20also%20called,(2)) and $(2)$ is derived from [this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the method I first met recently. It needs the Legendre Duplication Formula in (2).

Comment: @Lai You're welcome! I thought of Taylor expanding $\cosh(x)$ on my first attempt then tried to get creative after that, even if it ended up needing the Legendre Duplication Formula.