# Is the error function essential to $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-a x^2} \sinh (b x) d x$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, hyperbolic-functions, error-function

In the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4682138/732917),  there are 4 methods to find the integral

$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-a x^2} \cosh (b x) d x= \frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}},
$$
I believe that we can evaluate its partner integral
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-a x^2} \sinh (b x) d x$$

in a similar manner.

However, the integrand is unfortunately  **odd** and needs two results involving the error function [$\operatorname{erf}(x)$](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E8%AF%AF%E5%B7%AE%E5%87%BD%E6%95%B0) and its complementary function $\operatorname{erfc}(x)$:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-h(x-k)^2} d x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{h}}  \left[\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{h} k)+1\right] \tag*{(1)} 
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-h(x+k)^2} d x=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{h}}  \operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt{h} k) \tag*{(2)} 
$$

where $h,k>0$ and $
\operatorname{erfc}(x)=1-\operatorname{erf}(x)\cdots (3).
$

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be proved by the substitutions $y=\sqrt h(x+k)$.

Using the definition of $\cosh x$ and grouping the indices by the method of completing squares, we have
$$
I=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-a x^2} \sinh(b x) d x=\frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}}{2}\left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(e^{-a\left(x-\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2}-e^{-a\left(x+\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2}\right) d x\right.
$$

Now using $(1)-(3)$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}}+1\right)-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right)\right]\right. =\frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

**Are there any other forms of answers?**

Alternative methods and comments are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Feynman’s Trick**

Considering the integral parametrized by $b$
$$
I(b)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} \sinh (b x) d x
$$
with $I(0)=0$.

Differentiating w.r.t. $b$ gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(b) & =\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-ax^2} \cosh (b x) d x \\
& =-\frac{1}{2a} \int_0^{\infty} \cosh (b x) d\left(e^{-ax^2}\right) \\
& =-\frac{1}{2a}\left(\left[e^{-ax^2} \cosh (b x)\right]_0^{\infty}+ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} \sinh (bx) d x\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{b}{2a} I(b)
\end{aligned}
$$

Rearranging and solving by integrating factor gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I^{\prime}(b)-\frac{b}{2 a} I(b)=\frac{1}{2 a} \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad & {\left[e^{-\frac{b^2}{4 a}} I(b)\right]^{\prime}=\frac{1}{2 a} e^{-\frac{b^2}{4 a}} } \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad & e^{-\frac{b^2}{4 a}} I(b)=\frac{1}{2 } \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right) \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad & I(b)= \frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$